# How to solve such ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\{y_i\}_{i=0,...,d}$ be a sequences of functions depending on $x$ and satisfies $y'_i(x)=-\frac{(i+1)y_i(x)}{\sum_{i=0}^dy_i(x)}$ for $0\le i\le d$ with original conditions $y_d(0)=1$ and $y_i(0)=0$ for $i<d$ . And we assume $d\ge 3$. How can we solve such odes? Or an expression of $y_0+...+y_d$ only depends on $x$ is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y_i(0) = 0$, and $y_i'$ is proportional to $y_i$, one concludes that $y_i(x) = $ for all $x$. Which leaves $y_d' = - \frac{(d+1)y_d}{y_d} = -(d+1)$.

---

For a general case, you may observe that (as long as neither $y_i$ nor the denominator vanish) that

$$\frac{y_i'}{y_i} = (i+1) \frac{y_0'}{y_0}$$ therefore

$$y_i = a_i|y_0|^{i+1}$$

where $a_i$ shall be determined from the initial conditions. Substituting it back to the first equation gives

$$y_0' = -\frac{1}{\sum_0^d a_i |y_0|^i}$$

and, as long as $y_0 > 0$, one has

$$\sum_0^d\frac{a_i}{i+1}y_0^{i+1}(x) = C - x$$